# What is difference between ngrollup and webpack2 in angular4 or angular 2?

Tags: angular

Am working in angular4 project. It is not a single page application. Each components are bootstrapped as per project requirement.(to use in Magnolia). From angular4 build precept, i should generate a output files for each component. 
Folder for one component: 
component Name: login
Files present inside login component: 
1. login.module.ts // This module will contain child components
2. login.component.ts //login component imported in login.module.ts
3. login.component.html 
4. login.component.css

I should create a out put files similar to following format
output: 
1. login.min.js // what ever imported in login module should be combined to login.src.js
2. login.component.html// should be minify
3. login.component.css // should be minify

So i know, that  it can be done by using ngrollup. But can i use webpack-2. Which is advisable solution and is that possible to convert and minifiy type script to javascript for separate component using webpack-2?